# Директива препроцессора, которая только определяет макрос

Tags: c++, препроцессор

Дирекрива препроцесора `#define` может определят и переопределять макрос. Но синтаксис ее таков, что непонятно что конкретно она делает( определяет или переопределяет). Для того чтобы понять что она делает нужно учитывать какие директивы препроцессора исполнялись ранее. Из этого следует, что програмист, который хочет определить макрос,  может ошибочно переопределить макрос, который был определен где-то глубоко в подключенном заголовочном файле. Это приведет к ошибке, которою сложно найти. Какой код может строго:

- определить макрос
- переопределить макрос

Я написал такой код:

```
#define safe_define(def, val) \
#ifdef def \
#error "DEFINED!" \
#else \
#define def val \
#endif // def
```

Компилятор выдает ошибку на первой строке этого кода:

> main.cpp|17|error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter

Comment: Ошибка в этом коде или в вызывающем? Покажите 17 строку

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov изменил вопрос

Comment: снос строки убрать?

Comment: Вы не можете засунуть директивы препроцессора в директиву препроцессора, потому что они обрабатываются на одном и том же шаге компиляции.
Попросту говоря, это невозможно, если вы хотите избежать переопределения, вам везде надо писать раскрытый #ifndef / #define / #endif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> синтаксис ее таков, что непонятно что конкретно она делает

Понятно, определяет. Если определяемое уже где-то определено, то выбросится предупреждение (или ошибка, если компилятору сказано считать предупреждения ошибками).

> Компилятор выдает ошибку на первой строке этого кода:

С помощью директивы `#define` нельзя определить что-то, содержащее другие директивы препроцессора (кроме `##`). Поэтому ваш код и не собирается.

А чтобы проверить не переопределяется ли уже существующий макрос, ещё во времена динозавров придумали такой метод:

```
#ifndef FOO
# define FOO bar
#endif
```

Или:

```
#ifdef FOO
# undef FOO
# define FOO bar
#endif
```

Или даже:

```
#ifdef FOO
# error FOO must not be defined here!
#endif
```

Comment: "Если определяемое уже где-то определено, то переопределить не получится" - получится.
#define A 5
#define A 6

Comment: _"Если определяемое уже где-то определено, то переопределить не получится."_ - неправда. http://ideone.com/luTuiq

Comment: А, забыл что у меня просто алиас для gcc/g++ с `-Werror` прописан :)

Answer (score 6):

На второй стадии препроцессорной обработки исходного файла символы продолжения строки убираются, и смежные строки соединяются в одну строку.

Из стандарта C++ (2.2 Phases of translation)

> 2. Each instance of a backslash character (`\`) immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to
>      form logical source lines. Only the last backslash on any physical
>      source line shall be eligible for being part of such a splice. If, as
>      a result, a character sequence that matches the syntax of a
>      universal-character-name is produced, the behavior is undefined. A
>      source file that is not empty and that does not end in a new-line
>      character, or that ends in a new-line character immediately preceded
>      by a backslash character before any such splicing takes place, shall
>      be processed as if an additional new-line character were appended to
>      the file.

Только после этого происходит обработка макросов на стадии 4 (2.2 Phases of translation)

> 4. Preprocessing directives are executed, macro invocations are expanded, and >_Pragma unary operator expressions are executed. If a
>      character sequence that matches the syntax of a
>      universal-character-name is produced by token concatenation (16.3.3),
>      the behavior is undefined. A #include preprocessing directive causes
>      the named header or source file to be processed from phase 1 through
>      phase 4, recursively. All preprocessing directives are then deleted.

Учитывая эти цитаты из стандарта ваша директива `define` преобразуется к виду

```
#define safe_define(def, val) #ifdef def #error "DEFINED!" #else ...
```

Что не является корректной директивой, так как согласно разделу 16 Preprocessing directives

> 1 A preprocessing directive consists of a sequence of preprocessing
>   tokens that satisfies the following constraints: The first token in
>   the sequence is a # preprocessing token that (at the start of
>   translation phase 4) is either the first character in the source file
>   (optionally after white space containing no new-line characters) or
>   that follows white space containing at least one new-line character.
>   The last token in the sequence is the first newline character that
>   follows the first token in the sequence.146 A new-line character ends
>   the preprocessing directive even if it occurs within what would
>   otherwise be an invocation of a function-like macro.